# Form Button Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have been using ajax to load pages within my layout without having to refresh, I am now trying to do the same thing using forms but it doesn't work as I have been using href=''. How can I make it applicable to forms?
I have tried changing the .attr to button but it hasn't helped

http://jsfiddle.net/zn8Ex/2/

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('#load').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
return false
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The `action` attribute of the form is what you're looking for, also use the same `load()` method for the ajax.

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    $('#load').hide().load(url).fadeIn('normal');
    return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You when you use an anchor link `<a href="...">link</a>`, you are only visiting the page when you click it. No post data is sent.

If you want to use Jquery to post a form, use [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post( "test.php", postVar1: $("#someinput").val(), postVar2: $("#someinput").val() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the form via ajax and use it's success function to handle the new page load. If you use the code below, make sure to give your form an id of "login". Check out the fiddle below to see if it helps:

http://jsfiddle.net/zn8Ex/3/

```
$("#login").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./admin/login.php",
        data: $("#login").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
                // success message/ load new page here/ whatever you want to do after login
        }
    });
    return false; //prevent normal form submission
});
```